# How to install ng2-completer with angular cli and webpack

Tags: angular, angular5, ng2-completer

I am trying to install [ng2-completer](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer). It work just fine when I run `ng serve`. However, my `ng build --prod`. I get following error

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-completer/ng2-completer.module' in 'folder_path/front/src/app'

My package-lock.json is as follows:

```
"ng2-completer": {
            "version": "2.0.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ng2-completer/-/ng2-completer-2.0.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-IeW3sZft5jLYeDbMzxOSEWda2gs="
        },
```

I have tried importing package following ways:

```
import { Ng2CompleterModule } from '../../../../node_modules/ng2-completer/';
```

or

```
import { Ng2CompleterModule } from 'ng2-completer/';
```

I still get following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-completer/ng2-completer.module' in '/User/test/Document/front/src/app'
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with the 2.0.6 version of ng2-completer. I don't know the reason, but it seems that the problem does not occur in the previous version. As a quick fix You can try downgrading it to the 1.x:

`$ npm install ng2-completer@^1.0.0 --save`

Answer (score 3):

in angular 7.1.4 for using ngTable I had this Error and these follow commands worked for me.

npm i rxjs-compat --save

npm i ng2-completer --save

Answer (score -1):

In angular 6 I was facing the same issue because ng2-completer library or file was not present in package.json file while which on being installed with the given command worked for me:

**npm install ng2-completer --save**